# How can I put only value after decimal

Tags: python, floating-point

I have got output and I want to use only three values after decimal. How can i do that in Python?

Comment: deluge of rubbish questions continues

Comment: If you find Googling for "python string formatting" to be a challenge, then software development is not for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

round(number, 3)

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Answer (score 4):

Use the following:

```
"%.3f" % x
```

it converts your number to a string with three decimal places.

Answer (score 4):

In Python 2.6 or newer you should use the [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method:

```
>>> x = 15.23432
>>> '{0:.3f}'.format(x)
'15.234'
```